# VS Code highlight diffs against another git branch in the gutter

Tags: visual-studio-code

I really enjoyed the ability to press Alt-F5 to jump to the next block of code that I had edited, but now our source control processes will be changing and my changes will be committed more frequently meaning that fewer changes are visible in the editor since I am committing more often. Is there a way to treat another branch as the basis for the gutter highlighting and the "Next Difference" shortcut? I would like, for example, all the differences between my current branch and master or main to show in the gutter instead of just the uncommitted changes so I can quickly jump to blocks of code that have changed in the current branch whenever I have the file open in the default editor (not having to run a diff).

Comment: with the SCM - **File History** View you can open a diff editor with `Open Changes with Working File`, reduce the left part of the editor to "nothing"